# Count Number of Columns in XML

Tags: tables, luatex, luacode

I have successfully loaded `XML` in `LuaLaTeX` but how to load `XML-Tables`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
sample = [[
<datas>
  <arttitle>Quantum vacuum under mixed boundary conditions: the case for curved spacetime</arttitle>
  <table-wrap id="tab1" position="float">
  <label>Table 1ABC.</label>
  <caption id="t1"><p>The large <italic>x</italic> behavior for different <italic>w</italic>.</p></caption>
  <table>
  <colgroup>
  <col align="left"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  </colgroup>
  </table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>A1</th>
  <th>A2</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>B1</td>
  <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table-wrap>
</datas>]]
local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
tex.sprint(dom:query_selector("arttitle")[1]:get_text())

\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

It's printing article-title in `PDF`. How to do `number of columns` in `XML` and create in PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Here is how this XML file can be transformed to LaTeX and printed in the document. We can utilize the new `luaxml-transform` library which is present in the development version of [LuaXML](https://github.com/michal-h21/LuaXML).

Here is the updated TeX file:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574004/2891
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<datas>
  <arttitle>Quantum vacuum under mixed boundary conditions: the case for curved spacetime</arttitle>
  <table-wrap id="tab1" position="float">
  <label>Table 1ABC.</label>
  <caption id="t1"><p>The large <italic>x</italic> behavior for different <italic>w</italic>.</p></caption>
  <table>
  <colgroup>
  <col align="left"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="char" char="."/>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>A1</th>
  <th>A2</th>
  <th>A3</th>
  <th>A4</th>
  <th>A5</th>
  <th>A6</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>B1</td>
  <td>B2</td>
  <td>B3</td>
  <td>B4</td>
  <td>B5</td>
  <td>B6</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </table-wrap>
</datas>]]
local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
local alignments = {left="l", center="c", right="r"}

-- rules for conversion
transform.add_action("p", "%s\n\n")
transform.add_action("italic", "\\textit{%s}")
transform.add_action("arttitle", "\\noindent{\\large\\bfseries %s\\par\\noindent}")
transform.add_action("table-wrap", [[
\begin{table}
%s
\end{table}
]])

transform.add_action("label", "\\label{%s}")
transform.add_action("caption", "\\caption{%s}")
transform.add_action("table", [[
\begin{tabular}{@{data-columns}}
%s
\end{tabular}
]])

transform.add_action("tr", "%s \\\\")
transform.add_action("td", "& %s ")
transform.add_action("td:first-child", "%s ")
transform.add_action("th", "& %s ")
transform.add_action("th:first-child", "%s ")

 
-- get table columns
local function get_columns(tbl)
  local columns = {}
  for _, column in ipairs(tbl:query_selector("col")) do
    -- save column alignment. left is default
    local align = column:get_attribute("align") or "left"
    table.insert(columns, alignments[align])
  end
  return table.concat(columns, " ")
end

for i, tbl in ipairs(dom:query_selector("table")) do
  -- save table columns in table attribute, so it is available in transformation rules
  local columns = get_columns(tbl)
  tbl:set_attribute("data-columns", columns)
end

local converted = transform.process_dom(dom)
print(converted)
transform.print_tex(converted)


\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

In this case, we use the following code to set the tabular columns before the transformation:

```lua
-- get table columns
local function get_columns(tbl)
  local columns = {}
  for _, column in ipairs(tbl:query_selector("col")) do
    -- save column alignment. left is default
    local align = column:get_attribute("align") or "left"
    table.insert(columns, alignments[align])
  end
  return table.concat(columns, " ")
end

for i, tbl in ipairs(dom:query_selector("table")) do
  -- save table columns in table attribute, so it is available in transformation rules
  local columns = get_columns(tbl)
  tbl:set_attribute("data-columns", columns)
end
```

It sets the custom attribute, `data-columns`, with a value needed for the tabular environment based on the `align` attribute, like `l c c c c c` in this case.

The transformation rules are declared like this:

```lua
transform.add_action("label", "\\label{%s}")
```

The first argument is CSS selector that should be transformed. In the easiest case, it is just element name. The second argument is a template that will be used. `%s` is replaced with the element contents.

```lua
transform.add_action("table", [[
\begin{tabular}{@{data-columns}}
%s
\end{tabular}
]])
```

This more complicated transformation configures the table. `@{data-columns}` selects the `data-columns` attribute that we set earlier in the DOM processing function.

```lua
transform.add_action("td", "& %s ")
transform.add_action("td:first-child", "%s ")
```

This is an example of a more specific CSS rule. `&` characters are appended before table cells, except the first cell in each row.

This is the resulting PDF:

[image]

Another edit:

You can use this code as a standalone script to convert XML to LaTeX from the command line, `bxmltolatex.lua`:

```lua
kpse.set_program_name "luatex"
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"

-- read input from stdio
local sample = io.read("*all")

local dom = domobject.parse(sample)


-- rules for conversion
transform.add_action("p", "%s\n\n")
transform.add_action("italic", "\\textit{%s}")
transform.add_action("arttitle", "\\noindent{\\large\\bfseries %s\\par\\noindent}")
transform.add_action("table-wrap", [[
\begin{table}
%s
\end{table}
]])

transform.add_action("label", "\\label{%s}")
transform.add_action("caption", "\\caption{%s}")
transform.add_action("table", [[
\begin{tabular}{@{data-columns}}
%s
\end{tabular}
]])

transform.add_action("tr", "%s \\\\")
transform.add_action("td", "& %s ")
transform.add_action("td:first-child", "%s ")
transform.add_action("th", "& %s ")
transform.add_action("th:first-child", "%s ")

-- ignore colgroup
transform.add_action("colgroup", "")

 
-- get table columns
local alignments = {left="l", center="c", right="r"}

local function get_columns(tbl)
  local columns = {}
  for _, column in ipairs(tbl:query_selector("col")) do
    -- save column alignment. left is default
    local align = column:get_attribute("align") or "left"
    table.insert(columns, alignments[align])
  end
  return table.concat(columns, " ")
end

for i, tbl in ipairs(dom:query_selector("table")) do
  -- save table columns in table attribute, so it is available in transformation rules
  local columns = get_columns(tbl)
  tbl:set_attribute("data-columns", columns)
end

local converted = transform.process_dom(dom)
print(converted)
```

file.xml is:

```
<datas>
  <arttitle>Quantum vacuum under mixed boundary conditions: the case for curved spacetime</arttitle>
  <table-wrap id="tab1" position="float">
  <label>Table 1ABC.</label>
  <caption id="t1"><p>The large <italic>x</italic> behavior for different <italic>w</italic>.</p></caption>
  <table>
  <colgroup>
  <col align="left"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>A1</th>
  <th>A2</th>
  <th>A3</th>
  <th>A4</th>
  <th>A5</th>
  <th>A6</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>B1</td>
  <td>B2</td>
  <td>B3</td>
  <td>B4</td>
  <td>B5</td>
  <td>B6</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </table-wrap>
</datas>
```

Use it as:

```
texlua bxmltolatex.lua < file.xml > TransformedLatex.tex
```

Original answer:

You can use the `query_selector` on particular elements:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
sample = [[
<datas>
  <arttitle>Quantum vacuum under mixed boundary conditions: the case for curved spacetime</arttitle>
  <table-wrap id="tab1" position="float">
  <label>Table 1ABC.</label>
  <caption id="t1"><p>The large <italic>x</italic> behavior for different <italic>w</italic>.</p></caption>
  <table>
  <colgroup>
  <col align="left"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  <col align="center"/>
  </colgroup>
  </table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>A1</th>
  <th>A2</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>B1</td>
  <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table-wrap>
</datas>]]
local dom = domobject.parse(sample)


tex.sprint(dom:query_selector("arttitle")[1]:get_text())

tex.sprint("\\par")

local function get_columns(tbl)
  return #tbl:query_selector("col")
end
for i, tbl in ipairs(dom:query_selector("table")) do
  tex.sprint("Table: " .. i .. " has " .. get_columns(tbl) .. " columns")
end


\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

The important part is this:

```lua
local function get_columns(tbl)
  return #tbl:query_selector("col")
end
for i, tbl in ipairs(dom:query_selector("table")) do
  tex.sprint("Table: " .. i .. " has " .. get_columns(tbl) .. " columns")
end
```

It processes all tables in your document and it prints the column count calculated by  `#tbl:query_selector("col")` for every table.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, hope the `OP` wants to create a table output based on his XML tags, excuse me if I'm wrong...

Comment: @MadyYuvi I am not sure what OP really wants, so I am just answering how I understand it

Comment: @michal.h21: It's working fine. Exactly i have need to find the table total no of `col` elements. How to print all the `table` of elements in the PDF?

Comment: @Balaji it is bit more complicated. you will need some kind of XML to LaTeX transformation library like ones I posted in my earlier answers to your posts. I have updated version in the LuaXML development version.

Comment: @michal.h21: Okay I understood and would like to modify `XML` itself. Like `<colgroup>` need to change `<colgroup cols="number of columns here">` (Ex: <colgroup cols="7"). How to do this?

Comment: @michal.h21: I had tried `xmlout = string.gsub(xmlout,"<colgroup>","<colgroup cols=get_columns(tbl)>")` and not working...

Comment: @Balaji I've updated my answer.

Comment: @michal.h21: Amazing michal. It's exactly what i have needed and i will study the luaxml-transform`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Balaji it is still new code that isn't really documented anywhere yet. This is the first public presentation :)

Comment: @michal.h21: One small updations. Transformed `LaTeX` file will store in separate file like (Transformed-LaTeX.TeX) it will useful to find and fix the any bugs. It's possible?

Comment: @Balaji sure, you can extract just the script and use it from the command line. see the updated answer.

Comment: @Balaji please post it as a separate question, I will need to see your bibliography XML.

Comment: @michal.h21: How to find the `col with char` alignment (ex:  `align="char" char="."`)?

Comment: @Balaji I think it would be best if you could ask a new question for that, it is a separate problem from your original question.

Comment: @michal.h21: I have posted new question <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612213/table-char-alignment-in-xml>