# Table CHAR alignment in XML

Tags: lua, luacode, directlua

I have successfully loaded XML in LuaLaTeX with XML-Tables based on this example
[Count Number of Columns in XML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573960/count-number-of-columns-in-xml/574004#574004).

I have need the `table` alignments from `tbody` instead of `thead`. And how to define `alignment with char`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
sample = [[
<datas>
  <arttitle>Quantum vacuum under mixed boundary conditions: the case for curved spacetime</arttitle>
  <table-wrap id="tab1" position="float">
  <label>Table 1ABC.</label>
  <caption id="t1"><p>The large <italic>x</italic> behavior for different <italic>w</italic>.</p></caption>
  <table>
  <thead valign="top">
  <tr>
  <th align="center">Case n&#xb0;</th>
  <th align="center">1</th>
  <th align="center">2</th>
  <th align="center">3</th>
  <th align="center">4</th>
  <th align="center">5</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody valign="top">
  <tr>
  <td align="left">Sl. No</td>
  <td align="char" char=".">0.1</td>
  <td align="char" char=".">0.1</td>
  <td align="char" char=".">0.1</td>
  <td align="center">100</td>
  <td align="char" char=".">1.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>B1</td>
  <td>B2</td>
  <td>B3</td>
  <td>B4</td>
  <td>B5</td>
  <td>B6</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table-wrap>
</datas>]]
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think you can change column alignment in this way. You can use `siunitx`'s `S` colument to align table column to dot, but it doesn't work with this method: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47677/2891.

Comment: @michal.h21: How to find attribute with value in table alignments. Example: `align="char" char="."` and find in tbody instead of thead. I had tried `tbody tr[1]` it's not working.

Comment: you can find them with `td[align='char']`, but you will not be able to change the alignment in the LaTeX table cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<datas>
  <arttitle>Quantum vacuum under mixed boundary conditions: the case for curved spacetime</arttitle>
  <table-wrap id="tab1" position="float">
  <label>Table 1ABC.</label>
  <caption id="t1"><p>The large <italic>x</italic> behavior for different <italic>w</italic>.</p></caption>
  <table>
  <thead valign="top">
  <tr>
  <th align="center">Case n&#xb0;</th>
  <th align="center">1</th>
  <th align="center">2</th>
  <th align="center">3</th>
  <th align="center">4</th>
  <th align="center">5</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody valign="top">
  <tr>
  <td align="left">Sl. No</td>
  <td align="char" char=".">0.1</td>
  <td align="char" char=".">0.1</td>
  <td align="char" char=".">0.1</td>
  <td align="center">100</td>
  <td align="char" char=".">1.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>B1</td>
  <td>B2</td>
  <td>B3</td>
  <td>B4</td>
  <td>B5</td>
  <td>B6</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </table-wrap>
</datas>]]
local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
local alignments = {left="l", center="c", right="r"}

-- rules for conversion
transform.add_action("p", "%s\n\n")
transform.add_action("italic", "\\textit{%s}")
transform.add_action("arttitle", "\\noindent{\\large\\bfseries %s\\par\\noindent}")
transform.add_action("table-wrap", [[
\begin{table}
%s
\end{table}
]])

transform.add_action("label", "\\label{%s}")
transform.add_action("caption", "\\caption{%s}")
transform.add_action("table", [[
\begin{tabular}{@{data-columns}}
%s
\end{tabular}
]])

transform.add_action("tr", "%s \\\\")
transform.add_action("td[align='left']", "& \\multicolumn{1}{l}{%s}")
transform.add_action("td[align='left']:first-child", "\\multicolumn{1}{l}{%s}")
transform.add_action("td[align='char'][char='.']", "& \\multicolumn{1}{S}{%s}")
transform.add_action("td[align='char'][char='.']:first-child", "\\multicolumn{1}{S}{%s}")
transform.add_action("td", "& %s ")
transform.add_action("td:first-child", "%s ")
transform.add_action("th", "& %s ")
transform.add_action("th:first-child", "%s ")


-- get table columns
local function get_columns(tbl)
  local columns = {}
  for _, column in ipairs(tbl:query_selector("th")) do
    -- save column alignment. left is default
    local align = column:get_attribute("align") or "left"
    table.insert(columns, alignments[align])
  end
  return table.concat(columns, " ")
end

for i, tbl in ipairs(dom:query_selector("table")) do
  -- save table columns in table attribute, so it is available in transformation rules
  local columns = get_columns(tbl)
  tbl:set_attribute("data-columns", columns)
end

local converted = transform.process_dom(dom)
print(converted)
transform.print_tex(converted)
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

It reuses code from my previous answer, only new code is this:

```
transform.add_action("td[align='left']", "& \\multicolumn{1}{l}{%s}")
transform.add_action("td[align='left']:first-child", "\\multicolumn{1}{l}{%s}")
transform.add_action("td[align='char'][char='.']", "& \\multicolumn{1}{S}{%s}")
transform.add_action("td[align='char'][char='.']:first-child", "\\multicolumn{1}{S}{%s}")
```

It sets actions for `<td>` elements with `align` attribute. We duplicate code for each selector and use the`:first-child` pseudo class. This is necessary to handle `&` characters, you would get runtime LaTeX error about spurious `&` character otherwise.

It uses feature provided by the `siunitx` package, namely that it supports alignment by decimal point. Unfortunately, it works correctly only when specified in `tabular` declaration, it doesn't seem to have any effect on individual table cells, which is understandable.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: How to get the continued IDs? Example: `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B2">2</xref>&#x02013;<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B5">5</xref>`. I have need to convert `\citet{b2,b3,b4,b5}? Any help greatly appreciate...